# CPack NSIS component is Unspecified

Tags: c++, cmake, nsis, cpack

Behold the following fairly trivial CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

add_library(libdice SHARED lib.cpp)

set_target_properties(libdice PROPERTIES
    PREFIX ""
    OUTPUT_NAME "Dice"
    PUBLIC_HEADER "lib.h"
)

install(TARGETS libdice
    RUNTIME DESTINATION "lib"
    LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib"
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "include"
    COMPONENT sdk
)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "Dice SDK")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "NSIS")

include(CPack)

cpack_add_component(sdk)
```

With this `lib.h`:

```
#pragma once

int sides_of_a_dice();
```

And `lib.cpp`:

```
int sides_of_a_dice()
{
    return 6;
}
```

So if I `nmake package` for this on Windows it for some reason puts `Dice.dll` in an `Unspecified` component, even thought the component is clearly specified. Even weirder, the public headers (`lib.h`) correctly go in the `sdk` component.

```
CPack: Create package using NSIS
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: Project
CPack: - Install project: Project
CPack: -   Install component: Unspecified   <- Why??!
CPack: -   Install component: sdk
CPack: Create package
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation for [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html) command, **every specification** of file's type (like *RUNTIME*, *LIBRARY* or *PUBLIC_HEADER*) **starts its own install clause**, to which all other options are applied.

That is, option `COMPONENT sdk` is applied **only** to file's type `PUBLIC_HEADER`.

Other files (`RUNTIME`, `LIBRARY`) have component option *unspecified*.